# looping text file to get input entireis

Tags: python, file, loops, text, input

I have a script which asks the user to enter how much phones does the user want then ask the user for each phone number , but i want to make it easier like that :-
I want the user to create a phone file and ask the user for how much phones then i want the python to loop through the text file then copying the first number from phones.txt into the file "phone.txt" in the folders 1 , 2 , 3 then copy the second number to the folders 4,5,6 .. etc until the loop reach the number that user has entered .

PS : "PHONE NUMBER PER LINE IN THE TEXT FILE"

My current code :

```
phones = int(raw_input( "Phone count for perfix {0} : ".format(name)))
for i in range(phones):
    pho = int(raw_input( "Phone Number %d : " % (i+1)))
    phNums.append(pho)
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a range and store it in the list.
If I understand you very well, you are storing every phone number in three files. it should be something like that.

```
phones = int(raw_input( "Phone count for perfix {0} : ".format(name)))
copyTo= [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
for i in range(phone):
  for name in copyTo[i]:
    name+= '.txt'
    file = open(name,'w')
    file.close()
```

Comment: you're code is perfect , but one thing is missing i asked about removing the input and take the phone numbers from a text file also

Comment: Thanks! You should learn how to read and write from files using python. It's not that hard. Check :: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Comment: I know how to read and write but still the problem is how to read it like a this loop you could check my scenario again . When the user enter number 3 for the first question , it will go to the text file and copy the first number for the folder 1,2,3 and then etc ... this what i don't know about the loops

Comment: Try to use variable everytime to make it automated process.